# while em loop infinito usando $resultado = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Tags: php, pdo

```
<?php include ('pdo.php');
class crud
{
    public static function select($arg){
        $pdo = new pdoinit();
        $result = $pdo->prepare($arg);
        $result->execute();
        $resultado = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $resultado;
    }
}
$arr = crud::select('select * from grupos');
print_r($arr);
while ($row = $arr){
    echo $row['nome'];
}
```

Comment: `$row` saiu da onde? não ficou claro o problema.

Comment: $row é uma var que vai levar as informaçoes para o laço do while, var_dump($arr) vai retonar isso = "Array ( [id_grupo] => 12 [id_usuario] => 7 [nome] => Amigos ) "

Comment: pq vc precisa do while? pelo exemplo parece não precisar dele.

Comment: estou utilizando este while pra exibir informaçoes em um grid.
<?php
                    while ( $gridGrupo = crud::select('select * from grupos')){
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo '<th scope="row">'.$gridGrupo['id_grupo'].'</th>';
                        echo '<td>'.$gridGrupo['nome'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.' '.'</td>';
                    }
                ?>

Comment: Acho melhor [edit] a pergunta e colocar mais detalhes sobre o que vc deseja fazer e qual é  o problema ou resultado inesperado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem dois erros no seu código.

O primeiro erro é simples você está copiando infinitamente todo o conteúdo de `$arr` para `$row`, uma solução seria utilizar `foreach`.

```
foreach($arr as $row) {
   echo $row['nome'];
}
```

Vamos ao segundo erro, note que você está usando o `fetch` na linha `$resultado = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` o que irá retornar apenas uma linha por vez, então resultado terá um array associativo com a primeira linha, recomendo o uso do `fetchAll` assim essa linha ficaria assim:

```
    $resultado = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, deu certo!

Comment: O mais importante é que você entenda o porquê dos erros e funcionamento do código. ;)